# Please help explain about HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy

Tags: windows-7, volume-shadow-copy

I have 2 files on my C:\ drive:
C:\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy22  = 248 GB (266,455,478,272 bytes)
C:\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy26  = 357 GB (384,213,041,152 bytes)
for a total of 605 GB.
Are these real files or do they represent links to files on my other drives? I have 4 other drives that hold 3+ TB.

The problem is that my C: drive is only 240 GB.
Properties for C: are:
Used space: 160.774.803.456 bytes   149 GB
Free space: 48.940.392.448 bytes     45.5 GB
Capacity: 209.715.195.904byles      195GB  (28.29 GB Unallocated)

Can anyone explain, in laymen's terms, how Shadow Copy works?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Shadow copy stores snapshots of your hard disks and allows restoring if something goes wrong (e.g. a program or driver installation breaks Windows).

It's not a excuse not to do backups. If you are regularly doing backups, you can probably safely disable shadow copy. 
Even if you aren't, you still can disable shadow copy (although this is advised against).

It's also called "System restore" in the user interface.

If you feel comfortable turning off system restore:

- Open control panel
- Search for system
- Click system
- On left side click system protection
- Click configure
- Click turn of system protection or change the space you are allowing it to take up
- Press ok to commit change